# Android - It takes long to get a GPS-Signal. How to implement a good GPS provider?

Tags: android, gps, location-provider

i wrote an app, that tracks the gps location while jogging. Unfortunately the app needs some time to get a gps signal. When i open other apps like google maps, they are getting immediately the position.

My Problem is: How to implement the gps-provider, so that the app gets as fast as possible a signal.

One idea was, to start a service with the app, so that the provider does some preliminary work. But the tracking-activity is not the main-activity. How can i bind the service in an activity, that does not have started the service? Is this a good idea?

Thanks for reading - and i hope my english is understandable,

Martini

Comment: How long is "some time", 1 min? 5 min?  Typically TTFF (time to first fix) from a cold start in GPS in general can be as long as 15 minutes, as it takes a while to download the ephemeris data.

Comment: In most cases "some time" means 1-2 minutes. But some times "some time" means waiting for > 5 min. Cold start means: turning only gps on (monile phone may be running all the day) or turning mobile phone on?

Comment: I was more referring to general GPS, I am less familiar with the android implementation, but cold start will typically mean when the last known position is not available.  A hot start would be when the GPS is first turned on and the last know position is known  (which can help speed up satellite acquisition).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you first checking if there is a last known location which you can use? Most apps first check for it and then search for a location.

Comment: Now, I am checking for the last known location. The activity quickly shows the position. Many thanks! Martini.

Comment: But it still does need some time to get new positions. Has anyone an idea how to use the service, when it was started by the previous (main) activity? So the service could wait for location updates before the locations are needed?

Answer (score 9):

As I mentioned in my comments, GPS start up is not an instant process.  The receiver basically has to know the position of each of the GPS satellites in the constellation in order to calculate it's location.  The *ephemeris data* describes the positions of the satellites to the received and is downloaded from the satellites when the GPS is turned on (and I almost forgot to mention the *almanac data*, which is also part of the download and describes the orbits of the satellites). Things like downloading from multiple satellites and using the last known position can help speed up this initial process, but you cannot make it "instant".

There are other strategies that can be used to help speed up the location process, especially in cell phones.  In addition to the last-known position, things like Cell Tower + Timing positioning (ECID) or Wi-Fi positioning can be used in place of GPS while the GPS is still in the acquisition process.

This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html) describes some ideas on how to handle locating a mobile phone in android, but the short of it is:

- check last known position (discard if it is too old)
- check E-CID position (this is extremely fast, but is a very coarse
  location)
- check Wi-Fi position (this *can* be extremely accurate, but requires WiFi to be on and can sometimes have a large amount of error)
- finally obtain GPS position

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the link. I will try out described flow-model for obtaining locations. And your explaination helps me to understand the issue behind: getting gps-signals and accurate locations is a process that i have to define/implement. [Martini]

Comment: I think, the problem is solved. Now, i will follow the tipps an try to implement a proper way to handle the gps-topic in my app. [Martini]